# How to use a value in an input type=text in an if else statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made an interface for users to log their in and out times and to calculate the no. of hours worked. However, I don't fully understand the code I used so was hoping to find an easier option to understand.
I need to convert the in and out times from text to make another code to check if the employee had worked a full day (work hours>8hours) or if its a half day etc.

I used this to calculate the work hours (users enter the time as hh:mm)

```js
function diff(a, b) {
  function toTime(a) {
    return Date.parse('1970-01-01 ' + a.substr(0, 5)) / 1000 +
      (a.includes('PM') && (12 * 60));
  }
  var d = toTime(b) - toTime(a);
  return d >= 0 ? new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, d).toTimeString().substr(0, 5) : '';
}

function myFunction() {

  var workhours;

  workhours = diff($('#in-time').val(), $('#out-time').val());
  $('#value').val(workhours);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>In Time</th>
    <th>Out Time</th>
    <th>Hours Worked</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="in-time"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="out-time" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="value"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Edit : If anyone has an easier way to calculate the work hours based on the two inputs, it would be great if anyone can explain so I can learn it for future projects

Comment: Hello @hishma refer this link: http://jsbin.com/tecay/3/edit?html,output

Comment: @SandeshMankar I went through that code, but I got lost when I went deeper into the code. I'm still pretty new to javascript and have a lot to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else is trying to do something similar, I just made this code that works.
I will update it in a while with comments explaining how I got it to work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
var inTime = document.getElementById("in-time").value; // assume its 08:30
var outTime = document.getElementById("out-time").value;// assume its 17:30

var hours = inTime.split(':',1); // array = [08]
var hours2 = outTime.split(':',1); // array = [17]

var minutesArray = inTime.split(':',2); // array = [08,30]
var minutesArray2 = outTime.split(':', 2); // array = [17,30]

var minutes = minutesArray[1]; // select '30' from the array [08,30]
var minutes2 = minutesArray2[1]; // select '30' from the array [17,30]

var hoursToMinutes = hours * 60;
var hoursToMinutes2 = hours2 * 60;

var time = hoursToMinutes + parseInt(minutes);
var time2 = hoursToMinutes2 + parseInt(minutes2);

var workhours =(time2 - time)/60;

document.getElementById("workhours").innerHTML = workhours;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>In Time</th>
    <th>Out Time</th>
    <th>Hours Worked</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="in-time"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="out-time" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
    <td><span id="workhours"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```